# IntelliJ idea sbt project not displaying colours in terminal

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal, sbt

In one of sbt projects in IntelliJ that I'm working on there are control characters ("←[0m" string) instead of color inside the IntelliJ terminal

example

```
←[0m[←[0m←[0minfo←[0m] ←[0m←[0m←[36mTests: succeeded 2, failed 8, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0←[0m←[0m
←[0m[←[0m←[0minfo←[0m] ←[0m←[0m←[31m*** 2 SUITES ABORTED ***←[0m←[0m
←[0m[←[0m←[0minfo←[0m] ←[0m←[0m←[31m*** 8 TESTS FAILED ***←[0m←[0m
```

[no-color-terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EW0Hf.png)

In all other projects messages are displayed as expected

[color-terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyMVX.png)

Both projects use the same sbt version, unless there are some config parameters in the projects themselves that could cause this that I don't know about.
Additionally, I've been told that the colors display just fine on other machines, and now I'm really lost. What could be causing this?